# How to track status of email in sendgrid without using SMTP.

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I want to send emails which contain different contents to same user and I need to track their status. Are there any way to do that without using SMTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want [Unique Args](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/unique_arguments.html). These are called `custom_args` in the v3 API mail send argument, but it's the same concept.

Once you activate the [Event Webhook](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html), all events will include the appropriate unique_args, so you can relate each specific message to each.

Also, whenever you send a message to SendGrid, the acceptange response includes a message_id, which will be in all those events.

Comment: When we send a email through sendgrid it return
"  HTTP/1.1 202 " as response. It does not give any detail. 
https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/index.html
Also I couldn't find a way to get sent email details through sendgrid API.

Comment: In the body of that `202` will be a message_id. There's no way to query/"pull" information about messages via the API, but the Event Webhook will push data to you.

Comment: message_id is In the response header of 202 response.

Comment: Fast forward a few years, you can NOW pull information about messages. Relevant links: [API Reference](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/e-mail-activity/filter-all-messages), [Query Reference](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/getting-started-email-activity-api#query-reference). However there are some conditions to be met before this can be used. You will need to purchase additional email activity history. Once purchased, you must also update your existing API key(s) to have Email Activity access or create a new API key with Email Activity access.